# Using data in one table to get data from another

Tags: sql, ssms

I'm a little bit confused. I'm using SSMS for this.

"For each reservation for customer Ryan Goff, list the reservation ID, trip ID, and number of persons."

Ryan Goff is in the CUSTOMER table with the primary key being CUSTOMER_NUM.
All the others are in the RESERVATION table with the primary key being RESERVATION_ID and the foreign key being CUSTOMER_NUM

How would I get the list the reservation ID, trip ID, and number of persons just from the name? Wouldn't I also need to get the persons CUSTOMER_NUM in order to connect the values? How would I do that?

**Bold** = Primary Key

CUSTOMER(**CUSTOMER_NUM**, LAST_NAME, ADDRESS, CITY, STATE, POSTAL_CODE, PHONE)

RESERVATION(**RESERVATION_ID**, TRIP_ID, TRIP_DATE, NUM_PERSONS, TRIP_PRICE, OTHER_FEES, CUSTOMER_NUM)

Comment: it would be something like SELECT var1, var2, var3 FROM customer as c JOIN reservation as r USING(customer_num) WHERE first_name = 'Ryan' AND last_name = 'Goff'

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example - you did not provide a minimal reproducible example

Comment: MSSMS is suspiciously like SSMS which is sql-server - is this question tagged correctly?

Comment: @P.Salmon You're correct. Just changed the tags

Answer (score 0):

You can use the IN operator with a subquery to do this.

An example for this exact question would be:

```
SELECT RESERVATION_ID, TRIP_ID, NUM_PERSONS
FROM RESERVATION
WHERE CUSTOMER_NUM IN
(SELECT CUSTOMER_NUM
    FROM CUSTOMER
    WHERE FIRST_NAME = 'RYAN' AND LAST_NAME = 'Goff');
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve this is by joining the tables on the foreign key which would be the primary key in the customer table. See below:

```
SELECT RESERVATION_ID, TRIP_ID, NUM_PERSONS
FROM RESERVATION
INNER JOIN CUSTOMER NUM
ON RESERVATION.CUSTOMER_NUM = CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_NUM
WHERE CUSTOMER.FIRST_NAME = 'Ryan' AND CUSTOMER.LAST_NAME = 'Goff'
```